# libapr compilation fails when compiled through the Dockerfile, but works in an interactive session, why?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cross-compiling, riscv, apr

I'm trying to modify a [dockcross](https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross) image to include the Apache Portable Runtime lib inside of the Docker image for a riscv64 linux dockcross image. Here's the relevant command I've appended to the end of the Dockerfile:

```
RUN cd /tmp && \
    wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-1.6.3.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf apr-1.6.3.tar.gz && rm apr-1.6.3.tar.gz && \
    cd apr-1.6.3 && \
    ./configure --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=${CROSS_ROOT} && \
    make && \
    make install
```

Note that this works when I execute this within an interactive session for the image, but not when I try to build it. Any ideas on how to fix it? Thank you!

Steps to reproduce:

Modify the default Dockerfile from the dockcross repository by appending the above code snippet. The image build (with `make linux-riscv64` from the dockcross repo's root directory) should fail with the error message:

```
configure: error: Cannot determine size of void*
------
Dockerfile:127
--------------------
 126 |     # For now, we use a hardcoded apr version (1.6.3), might want to change that later
 127 | >>> RUN cd /tmp && \
 128 | >>>     wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-1.6.3.tar.gz && \
 129 | >>>     tar -xvf apr-1.6.3.tar.gz && rm apr-1.6.3.tar.gz && \
 130 | >>>     cd apr-1.6.3 && \
 131 | >>>     ./configure --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=${CROSS_ROOT} && \
 132 | >>>     make && \
 133 | >>>     make install
 134 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cd /tmp &&     wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-1.6.3.tar.gz &&     tar -xvf apr-1.6.3.tar.gz && rm apr-1.6.3.tar.gz &&     cd apr-1.6.3 &&     ./configure --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=${CROSS_ROOT} &&     make &&     make install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
make: *** [Makefile:248: linux-riscv64] Error 1
```

I am trying to build the docker image from an x86_64 Linux host.